# unity タグは何を指す？

Tags: 討議, タグ

コンピュータと関係がある「Unity」は複数知られています。たとえば以下のものがあります。

- ゲームエンジン [Unity](https://unity3d.com/jp) ([unity3d](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d))
- Ubuntu の GUI [Unity](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(%E3%83%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9)) ([ubuntu-unity](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-unity))
- マイクロソフトのコンテナ [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ff647202.aspx) (本家 SO でのタグは [unity-container])
- VMware の [Unity モード](https://japan.zdnet.com/keyword/Unity%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89/)

この内、タグ [unity](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) が参照すべきはどれでしょうか？　あるいは、タグ [unity](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) は一切使わない方が良いでしょうか？

私の意見は自己回答として投稿いたしますので、最も良いと思うものに **プラス投票** して頂ければと思います。ご意見ある方は是非回答としてご投稿ください。

Comment: タグの無い後者2つは現在質問が無い状態ですかね？、タグが無いと知らないユーザは「`vmware` `unity`」など`unity`単体でつけてしまいそうな気がします。タグ説明にもこのMETA結果を反映したいですね。

Comment: @Myaku 「タグの別名」にすると [unity] タグに特化したタグ wiki が書けなくなるので、確かにそうですね。良いご指摘ありがとうございます。「unity -[unity3d] -[unity2d]」で検索したところ、VMware のものに関しては1つ質問があるようでした。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/14994/19110

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[unity](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity) は [unity3d](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) のタグシノニム (タグの別名) にすべきだと思います。

日本語版スタック・オーバーフローにおいて「Unity」といえば、[unity3d](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) を指していることが多いと思うからです。また、本家 SO で[議論の末](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269701/5989200)、[unity] が [unity3d] のタグシノニムに設定されたこととも整合性が取れます。

---

#### 2017年12月8日追記

他の Unity と混同しないよう、[unity3d](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) のタグ wiki 抜粋を書き換えるための案を書きます。

現在は

> Unity とは、統合開発環境を内蔵し、複数のプラットホームに対応する、ユニティ・テクノロジーズが開発したゲームエンジンである。ウェブブラウザ、デスクトッププラットフォーム、ゲーム機、携帯機器向けのコンピュータゲームを開発するために用いられる。

と書かれているところを、以下のように書き換えるのは如何でしょうか。

> 他の Unity と混同しないよう気をつけて下さい。ここで言う Unity とは、ユニティ・テクノロジーズが開発したクロスプラットフォームなゲームエンジンです。3D/2D のアプリやゲーム、シミュレーションを作ることができ、VR や AR へ応用することもできます。

Comment: unity3d <- unity のシノニム設定を行いました。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all

Comment: 2017年12月26日にタグwiki抜粋編集リクエストが通ったので、タグwiki抜粋もアップデートされました。